# Citations error

Tags: citations

I published a paper and I have it in my profile. While I can find other versions of that which have different citations. The problem is that some of the citations from other versions are not included in the main version. I tried to merge all the versions but the problem is that it hasn’t been corrected for my co-authors’ profile.
Would you provide me a solution to fix the citations correction permanently for my and other authors’ profile?
Bellow you can find the link of the main paper and other versions.

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=zJP21xcAAAAJ&citation_for_view=zJP21xcAAAAJ:4TOpqqG69KYC

Comment: The shared URL is broken for public view

Answer (score 1):

Based on Google's official [FAQ](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#questions), you can edit your own profile and ask your co-authors to do so on their sides. You can edit/merge articles in your own profile, however, it does not guarantee affecting the citation count.